Unable to connect to single-node mongodb replica set with pymongo in docker compose
The task is to set up a MongoDB replica set from a single node and connect to it from another container using pymongo.
After running docker compose up -d, the behavior is as follows:
The connection to the database is successful through:

MongoDB Compass: mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017
docker exec -it api mongosh mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb

However, connecting to the database via pymongo fails:
docker exec -it api python3
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb")
client.server_info()  # fails with an error


pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Could not reach any servers in [('localhost', 27017)]. Replica set is configured with internal hostnames or IPs? Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: ..., topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused...')>]

It seems the issue arises because of { _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' } in rs.initiate(). I tried replacing localhost with mongodb and resolving the hostname to an IP, but MongoDB crashes with a error in all these cases:

couldn't connect to server mongodb:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongodb:27017 (172.18.0.2:27017) :: caused by :: syncConnect connect error :: caused by :: Connection refused


No host described in the new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node, "config": {"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongodb:27017"}]

Although from within the mongodb container, it is possible to resolve the hostname and connect to the database via mongosh.
In conclusion, the issue seems to lie not with MongoDB but with pymongo, since other methods of connecting to the database work fine. I see the solution either in changing the mongodb configuration, or in something else in pymongo configuration
Structure
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mongodb
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── generate-keyfile.sh
│   ├── init.js
│   └── mongod.conf

docker-compose.yml
services:
  mongodb:
    build:
      context: ./mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12.1-alpine3.19

RUN pip3 install pymongo
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
RUN npm install -g mongosh

CMD tail -f

Mongodb
mongodb/Dockerfile
FROM mongo:latest

COPY generate-keyfile.sh /generate-keyfile.sh

RUN mkdir -p /opt/keyfile && \
    /bin/bash /generate-keyfile.sh

COPY mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf
COPY init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js
CMD ["mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongod.conf"]

mongodb/mongodb.conf
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /opt/keyfile/mongo-keyfile

replication:
  replSetName: rs0

mongodb/init.js
rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' }]});

sleep(10000)
var adminDB = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
adminDB.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'admin', roles: [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }]});

Additional information
rs.status() ->
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:26.501Z'),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long('2'),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long('2000'),
  majorityVoteCount: 1,
  writeMajorityCount: 1,
  votingMembersCount: 1,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 1,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 }), t: Long('2') },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:16.735Z'),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 }), t: Long('2') },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 }), t: Long('2') },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 }), t: Long('2') },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:16.735Z'),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:16.735Z')
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1726305466, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate('2024-09-14T08:51:46.749Z'),
    electionTerm: Long('2'),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1726303904, i: 4 }), t: Long('1') },
    numVotesNeeded: 1,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long('10000'),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate('2024-09-14T08:51:46.753Z'),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate('2024-09-14T08:51:46.756Z')
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'localhost:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 1601,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 }), t: Long('2') },
      optimeDate: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:16.000Z'),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:16.735Z'),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('2024-09-14T09:18:16.735Z'),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1726303906, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate('2024-09-14T08:51:46.000Z'),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 2,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64('VqlzRHy12WaSQvdaNlDJn08ffBU=', 0),
      keyId: Long('7414418767687450630')
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1726305496, i: 1 })
}

Versions
mongodb - 7.0.14
python - 3.12.1
pymongo - 4.8.0
mongosh - 2.3.1

Even though 10 seconds should be sufficient, better replace sleep(10000) by while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000);

In general you are right, but here i have no troubles with this.
